# Apply OOTB Compsed Look

Tags: 2013, theme

I have successfully created a feature to provision my custom masterpage to my site collection, with a feature receiver that applies it on activation, which also sets my custom theme, like so:

```
SPTheme theme = SPTheme.Open("HebronTheme", colorPaletteFile);
theme.ApplyTo(site.RootWeb, true);
```

Now I want to set the theme back to the default Office Composed Look on deactivation. I have tried applying the default color palette in the same way I set my custom color palette, but wouldn't it make more sense to reset the site to an existing theme, rather then another custom theme?

How can I programmatically apply an existing theme/Composed Look? (Or is there another way to go about this?)

Thanks for any suggestions.